# How can I call `res.json` after `await` Node js?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, https, async-await

I need to send data from one node server to another node server.
On the first server, I create a https.request.

```
app.get('/menu',(res,req,next)=>{
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        login: req.body.login,
        pass: req.body.pass
    });
      
    var optionsProps = {
      host : '192.168.5.75',
      port : 3000,
      path : '/property',
      method : 'GET',
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      }
    }
    var httpreqProps = https.request(optionsProps, (httpres)=>{
      httpres.setEncoding('utf8');
      httpres.on('data',(chunk) =>{
        console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
        next();
      })
    })
    httpreqProps.write(data);
    httpreqProps.end();
}
```

On the second I answer.

```
app.get('/property',(res,req,next)=>{
    (async () => {
            try {

                let pool = await sql.connect();

                let result = await pool.request()
                    .input('Usr',sql.NVarChar,userName)
                    .output('ErrInfo',sql.NVarChar)
                    .execute('WEB_API_GetElementsStruct');

                if(result.output['ErrInfo'] != null && result.output['ErrInfo'] !== undefined && result.output['ErrInfo'] !== '')
                    res.status(500).json({message:result.output['ErrInfo']})
                else {

                    let keys = Object.keys(result.recordsets[0][0]);
     
                    let struct = JSON.parse(result.recordsets[0][0][keys[0]]);

                    if(struct) {
                        let data = {fields:[]};
                        data.fields = struct;
                        res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(data));
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    res.status(500).json({message:'Menu is empty or query have an errors!'});
                }
            } catch (err) {
                res.status(500).json({message:err.message});
            }
        })();
}
```

And I get in the logs `GET /propety - - ms - -`.
But when I send request the second server from the browser ajax, it responds correctly.
Also if I write `res.json` before `await` everything works correctly.
How can I call `res.json` after `await`?

Comment: Side note, you should just write `async (res,req) =>` instead of `(res,req,next)=>{ (async () => {`. Otherwise, at first glance, this code looks pretty good to me, good use of `await`. Try `.json(data)` instead of `.json(JSON.stringify(data))`.

Comment: I have already tried this. The result is the same.